# CSS file not being called in Shopify

Tags: html, css, function, call

I am using shopify to customize my store and have had no issues calling a css flie. 
The way my homepage is setup is the homepage is split into 2 files.

First deals with the headers and so forth and it's labeled theme.liquid
Second deals with the rest of the page, carousel images, and so forth. That file is labeled index.liquid

In the theme.liquid, I called `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smedia.css.liquid">` and have had no issues calling that css file.

In the index.liquid, I call `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexButtons.css.liquid">` to have an opacity functionality on hovers. The css works fine as I have tested the files in jsfiddle. Link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nu0brxag/)

My issue is, in index.liquid, I cannot get the css files called to have that highlight on hover. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Of course there's a reason. A link to the actual site would help, though, as then it's easy to tell what's happening with the code.

Comment: www.billiyen.com @ralph.m

Comment: OK, there must be an issue with how you are using their system. This line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css.liquid">` is on the page rather than in the head, and the style sheet is empty. I would advise you read up on the docs ... or just put all styles in the one style sheet that is working (which is better anyway, imho).

Comment: @ralph.m good point, let me try messing around with the code, see if I can get the code to work